# C fscanf delimiter with a long

Tags: c

I'm trying to read from a .csv file in C and it works for my character arrays, but not for my long.

```
char fname[24];
char lnem[48];
char email[36]
long phone;

fscanf(fp, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]%*s,%lf", fname, lname, email, phone);
```

Comment: you need to pass a pointer (`&phone`).

Comment: Enable all compiler warnings and save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line should be

```
fscanf(fp, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%ld", fname, lname, email, &phone);
//           removed %*s ----^  ^---- format specifier   ^---- address-of operator
```

Comment: Hmmm, `fscanf(fp, "%[^,],%[^,]...` is akin to `gets()`.  Perhaps `fscanf(fp, "%23[^,],%47[^,],%35[^,],%ld", fname, lname, email, &phone);`?

Comment: @chux that's an improvement - I was focussing on the immediate problem. But it needs more than that: the inputs will get mixed up if the length constraint is hit.